# ASP MVC 5: index or statistics with name 'IX_Id' already exists on table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to create an order table with a **shipping adress** field and a **billing address** field. I thought it would be smart to create an OrderAddress model and then *associate it twice*, one for the shipping address and one for the billing address.

This is how I "envisioned" it.

[image]

**My corresponding models**

```
public class Order : BaseModel
{
    public Order()
    {
        this.OrderLines = new HashSet<OrderLine>();
    }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }

    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public int DistributorProfileId { get; set; }
    public virtual DistributorProfile Distributor { get; set; }
    public int BillingAddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual OrderAddress BillingAddress { get; set; }
    public int ShippingAddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual OrderAddress ShippingAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class OrderAddress : BaseModel
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

---

However, when I run `Update-Database`, I get this error:

> The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_Id'
>   already exists on table 'dbo.Orders'.

I understand what it means, so I would like to assign **different names** to the foreign keys. Is that possible?

### Bonus

Is there maybe a design flaw here? Should I create my models differently?

Answer (score 0):

```
I think if you can add a Key column like an Id to your Order address table:

public class OrderAddress : BaseModel
{
pulbic int Id{get;set;}
}

and using model binder

modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasOptional(x => x.BillingAddress).WithMany().HasForeignKey(u => u.BillingAddressId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasOptional(x => x.ShippingAddress).WithMany().HasForeignKey(u => u.ShippingAddressId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```